# Error downloading following URL using urlread() function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, post, urlread

I am trying to download the contents of following url.

```
'https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/ReferenceRateArchive.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTIwODkzNjIzMjMPZBYCAgEPZBYEAhMPFgIeBXN0eWxlBQ5kaXNwbGF5OmJsb2NrO2QCFQ8WAh4EVGV4dAWpBDx0cj48dGQgY2xhc3M9InRhYmxlaGVhZGVyIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwIiBhbGlnbj0ibGVmdCI%2BPGI%2BRGF0ZTwvYj48L3RkPjx0ZCBjbGFzcz0idGFibGVoZWFkZXIiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAiIGFsaWduPSJyaWdodCI%2BIDxiPlVTRCA8L2I%2BPC90ZD48dGQgY2xhc3M9InRhYmxlaGVhZGVyIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwIiBhbGlnbj0icmlnaHQiPiA8Yj5HQlAgPC9iPjwvdGQ%2BPHRkIGNsYXNzPSJ0YWJsZWhlYWRlciIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMCIgYWxpZ249InJpZ2h0Ij4gPGI%2BRVVSTyA8L2I%2BPC90ZD48dGQgY2xhc3M9InRhYmxlaGVhZGVyIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwIiBhbGlnbj0icmlnaHQiPiA8Yj5ZRU4gPC9iPjwvdGQ%2BPC90cj48dHI%2BPHRkIGhlaWdodD0iMjAiID4wOS8xMi8yMDE1PC90ZD48dGQgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMCIgYWxpZ249InJpZ2h0Ij42Ni43NTAwPC90ZD48dGQgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMCIgYWxpZ249InJpZ2h0Ij4xMDAuMjkxOTwvdGQ%2BPHRkIGhlaWdodD0iMjAiIGFsaWduPSJyaWdodCI%2BNzIuODkxMDwvdGQ%2BPHRkIGhlaWdodD0iMjAiIGFsaWduPSJyaWdodCI%2BNTQuNDAwMDwvdGQ%2BPC90cj5kGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYFBQZjaGtBbGwFBmNoa0dCUAUGY2hrWUVOBQZjaGtVU0QFB2Noa0VVUk%2BSGzV8Q4%2BQGdZtI0VOgWvaW1E0%2Fw%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=6A117BB1&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAA8aLAsLo%2FHwSaeBXCXmZilSi6wX7g7V%2B51d5y%2FuZ409MWQ6cu1iZ73N7YF2NPAmCyQ%2Fq33cCQLgaFQSElESF1pcfcX9ZaEV78oETjPwNTvjRyaLpyghhgB3dOM81YQT2c9%2F%2BgftA0sfXfDVAjh7xSqBhaW9lcSH1kY5FCWz6Xgykl1T0rRV1xwZiwEqKxacpKD8aEimM%2Bv26W4ZAE5GN0Z6WPN56Qs62BAJnF597e6LXUPcYsL56nHH9LNw6EJeV0k6GX39ewFFXMEeUx5%2B6kZrPOaW1pQztoQA36D1w%2F%2BbXfeorZxJNEQSFMcpSqWnvJrdd0ojQdhtywgKjNvYCs8173Xmjw%3D%3D&UsrFontCntr%24txtSearch=&chkAll=on&txtFromDate=09%2F12%2F2015&txtToDate=09%2F12%2F2015&btnSubmit=+GO+#mainsection'
```

Now when I put this url in browser, I get the desired web page. I tried successfully reading it's HTML contents using Python's `urllib2` library as well.

But while reading the same URL using urlread() in Matlab, I get following error:

```
??? Error using ==> urlread at 108
Error downloading URL.
```

How can I read the corresponding HTML using urlread() in Matlab?

Note : The request is POST request.

Edit : I tried using `urlread(URL_name, 'Post', {list of parameters})` syntax. But still getting the same error.

Comment: You can study the code of the function you have prblem with by typing `open urlread`

Comment: `urlread` reads HTML pages.  The URL you are feeding is a Microsoft ASP page.  It doesn't work.

Comment: @rayryeng I am not sure if that is correct. Actually existing code-base of my project has calls to urlread() with **.aspx** pages as parameters.